# Mounted drives show incorrect size and free space

Tags: samba, file-server

I have two USB drives mounted using Samba as network drives using my Raspberry Pi.

My Windows machine and backup software show incorrect size and used space for the drives.

View from Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ df -h

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on

rootfs 3.4G 3.0G 195M 94% /

/dev/root 3.4G 3.0G 195M 94% /

devtmpfs 214M 0 214M 0% /dev

tmpfs 44M 2.1M 42M 5% /run

tmpfs 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock

tmpfs 88M 4.0K 88M 1% /run/shm

/dev/mmcblk0p5 60M 19M 41M 32% /boot

/dev/sda1 932G 591G 341G 64% /mnt/shares/PiHDD1 ((CORRECT))

/dev/sdb1 2.8T 152M 2.8T 1% /mnt/shares/PiHDD2 ((CORRECT))

/dev/mmcblk0p3 27M 929K 24M 4% /media/SETTINGS_
```

The capacity and usage is correct

View from Windows 7.

```
PiHDD1 194 MB free of 3.34GB 
PiHDD2 194 MB free of 3.34GB
```

The drive capacity and space used space are wrong.

Can anyone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your shares are pointing to the rootfs partition.  If you look at the first two entries, you'll see they they match what Windows is reporting.

You need to reconfigure your share so that they're pointing to `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`.